# Real-time Unplanned Streaming from Hardware devices to mobile phones and web

Tags: android, ios, video, streaming, video-streaming

What are the possible solutions for video livestreaming from hardware devices to mobile phones, in the following conditions:
 - Devices will stream video upon request (which is an unplanned event)
 - Each device needs to have a separate livestream channel, so clients can see only their own stream
 - Able to start and stop streaming channels on demand. 
 - Able to encode the video in different formats for Android, Web, and iOS.
 - Able to stream secured encrypted video.

So far we've investigated Azure Media Services (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/media-services-overview/) and Wowza (https://www.wowza.com/). 
Both of them are really great streaming solutions, backed by strong CDN's, but they are fitted only to planned events, where you want to stream video on demand to a large audience.

We've also started to investigate into P2P networks, the only problem that we see so far is the connection from devices that are behind a symmetric NAT (that is usually changing ports upon each request).

Are there any solutions that you guys can recommend?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for looking at our technology. Your comment about not limitations of our technology caught my eye.

I'd be happy to discuss how other developers have implemented our product on their own virtual systems to achieve an instant-on live streaming service similar to those built & operated by Wowza clients like Periscope, Livestream.com, and Justin.TV (a site later known as Twitch).

yours,
John from Wowza

PS: Please pardon me if this looks like sales spam. I'm an engineer here at Wowza and we're always genuinely curious to learn about limitations clients find in deploying our technology.

Answer (score 0):

Wowza Streaming Engine supports and on-demand workflow. The mobile device will publish to Wowza, which will kickoff the streaming process - no intervention is required. As soon as the incoming stream connected, the stream becomes available to your media players. Server-side, you can enable capabilities like live transcoding (for adaptive bit rate), DVR as well as security configurations like SSL and AES encryption.

For CDN, you can push directly from Wowza to the provider of your choice. Can also stand up Wowza as an HTTP origin for HLS distribution.

A lot of this depends on your scale. Getting started, a single instance of Wowza will enable you to dial-in your configuration. As you scale, again, you can leverage a CDN or add Wowza edge servers as needed.

Delivery, of course, is available to all the target devices in reference.

Give it a try...

**How to install and configure Wowza Streaming Engin**e - https://www.wowza.com/docs/how-to-install-and-configure-wowza-streaming-engine

**How to connect the Wowza GoCoder encoding app to Wowza Streaming Engine** - https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?635-How-to-connect-the-Wowza-GoCoder-encoding-app-to-Wowza-Streaming-Engine

Note: Wowza also is developing an SDK for the GoCoder mobile app, which can streamline adding an encoder to your app.